# swift 3 content mode

Tags: ios, swift3

I have a problem with xcode: I created a draw app where you can draw on the pictures, when I open a picture and I click to draw, the image stretches,
the same thing if I change content mode (aspectFit, aspectFill)
I forget something?
how to set up the content mode correctly?

This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Photos

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var toolIcon: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var tempImage: UIImageView!

    var lastPoint = CGPoint.zero
    var swiped = false

    var red: CGFloat = 0.0
    var green: CGFloat = 0.0
    var blue: CGFloat = 0.0

    var brushWidth:CGFloat = 10.0
    var opacity:CGFloat = 1.0

    var tool: UIImageView!
    var isDrawing = true
    var selectedImage: UIImage!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
        tempImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill

        tool = UIImageView()
        tool.frame = CGRect(x:self.view.bounds.size.width, y: self.view.bounds.size.height, width: 38, height: 38)
        //tool.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Pen")
        self.view.addSubview(tool)
    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?){
        swiped = false
        if let touch = touches.first {
            lastPoint = touch.location(in: self.view)
        }
    }

    func drawLines(fromPoint:CGPoint, toPoint:CGPoint){
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
        tempImage.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: self.view.frame.width,height: self.view.frame.height))
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        context?.move(to:CGPoint(x:fromPoint.x,y:fromPoint.y))
        context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:toPoint.x, y: toPoint.y))
        tool.center = toPoint

        context?.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.normal)
        context?.setLineCap(CGLineCap.round)
        context?.setLineWidth(brushWidth)
        context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0).cgColor)
        context?.strokePath()

        tempImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        tempImage.alpha = opacity
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?){
        swiped = true

        if let touch = touches.first {
            let currentPoint = touch.location(in: self.view)
            drawLines(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: currentPoint)

            lastPoint = currentPoint
        }

    }

    override  func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if !swiped {
            drawLines(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: lastPoint)
        }

        // Merge tempImageView into mainImageView
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.frame.size)
        imageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height), blendMode: CGBlendMode.normal, alpha: 1.0)
        tempImage.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height), blendMode: CGBlendMode.normal, alpha: opacity)
        imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        tempImage.image = nil

    }

    @IBAction func reset(_ sender: Any) {
        self.imageView.image = nil
    }



    @IBAction func colorPicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if sender.tag == 0 {
            (red,green,blue) = (1,0,0)
        }else if sender.tag == 1 {
            (red,green,blue) = (0,1,0)
        }else if sender.tag == 2{
            (red,green,blue) = (0,0,1)
        }else if sender.tag == 3 {
            (red,green,blue) = (1,0,1)
        }else if sender.tag == 4{
            (red,green,blue) = (1,1,0)
        }else if sender.tag == 5 {
            (red,green,blue) = (0,1,1)
        }else if sender.tag == 6{
            (red,green,blue) = (1,1,1)
        }else if sender.tag == 7 {
            (red,green,blue) = (0,0,0)
        }
        }
    @IBAction func save(_ sender: Any) {
        let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Pick your options", message: "", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Pick an image", style: .default, handler: { (_) in

            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            imagePicker.delegate = self

            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }))

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save your drawing", style: .default, handler: {(_) in
            if let image = self.imageView.image {
                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil,nil,nil)
            }
        }))

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil))
        present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func erase(_ sender: Any) {
        if (isDrawing) {
            (red,green,blue) = (1,1,1)
            tool.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Gomma")
            toolIcon.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Pen"), for: .normal)

        }else {
            (red,green,blue) = (0,0,0)
            tool.image = nil
            toolIcon.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Gomma"), for: .normal)
        }
        isDrawing = !isDrawing
    }


    @IBAction func setting(_ sender: Any) {
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

        let settingsVc = segue.destination as! SettingViewController
        settingsVc.delegate = self
        settingsVc.red = red
        settingsVc.green = green
        settingsVc.blue = blue

        settingsVc.brush = brushWidth
        settingsVc.opacity = opacity
    }
}


extension ViewController:UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,SettingsVCDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let imagePicked = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage  {
            self.selectedImage = imagePicked
            self.imageView.image = selectedImage
            self.tempImage.image = selectedImage



            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func settingsViewControllerDidFinish(_settingsVc: SettingViewController) {
        self.red = _settingsVc.red
        self.green = _settingsVc.green
        self.blue = _settingsVc.blue
        self.brushWidth = _settingsVc.brush
        self.opacity = _settingsVc.opacity

    }
}
```

Comment: where are your constraints ?

Comment: And check if method `imagePickerController(didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo)` is called. i think this is your problem

Comment: The constrains are correct, the app works but when I import an image appears stretched
I noticed that the console appears this warning: [Generic] Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error